# How to find minimum no. of steps to make an array non-decreasing by selecting any interval and adding '1' to all items in the interval at each step?

Tags: arrays, sorting, dynamic-programming, lcs

Given an array, we need to find the minimum number of steps in which we can make it non decreasing. 
We can select i & j and add '1' to all the elements in the interval a[i] to a[j] (both inclusive) at each step

```
for eg: A={3,2,1}
        answer is 2.
        step1 : {3,3,2} i=1,j=2
        step2 : {3,3,3} i=2,j=2
```

I think it can be solved using DP but cant think of it......plz help

Comment: Are you sure about what you can do at each step? I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't always have j as the maximum value, in which case it is just a question of adding the differences when sequential items are decreasing.

Comment: I think you need to do a lot more work here before we can help you. At least post some code to show you've tried something.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be done via a trick which turns out to be useful when observed. What I do is find all the strictly decreasing subarrays of the main array and subtract their first and last elements(Highest-lowest) and add. The result is the minimum steps required.

```
int min_step(int arr[],int n)
{
    int step=0,max=arr[0];
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==x || arr[i]>=arr[i-1]);
        {
            step+=(max-arr[i-1]);
            max=arr[i];
        }
    }
    return step;
}
```

For eg. if I take the array to be:

```
arr[4]={11,8,4,54}
```

The answer is 7.(How?)

```
11 8 4 54
Choosing {8,4} and increasing 3 times
11 11 7 54
Choosing {7} and increasing 4 times
11 11 11 54
Which is the required array
```

The algorithm computes the same answer by using the only decreasing subarray (11,8,4) and 11-4=7

This works due to the fact that if we find the decreasing subarray, the element next to the smallest element is first leveled and then the range of increasing is increased subsequently.